# Read files from a PCollection of GCS filenames in Pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming pipeline hooked up to pub/sub that publishes filenames of GCS files. From there I want to read each file and parse out the events on each line (the events are what I ultimately want to process).

Can I use TextIO? Can you use it in a streaming pipeline when the filename is defined during execution (as opposed to using TextIO as a source and the fileName(s) are known at construction). If not I'm thinking of doing something like the following:

Get the topic from pub/sub
ParDo to read each file and get the lines
Process the lines of the file...

Could I use the FileBasedReader or something similar in this case to read the files? The files aren't too big so I wouldn't need to parallelize the reading of a single file, but I would need to read a lot of files.

Comment: We're close to having sufficient API support to create an efficient implementation of this. Please follow https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2511 TextIO should support reading a PCollection of filenames.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the new API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `TextIO.readAll()` transform, which has been recently added to Beam in [#3443](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3443). For example:

```
PCollection<String> filenames = p.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings()...);
PCollection<String> lines = filenames.apply(TextIO.readAll());
```

This will read all lines in each file arriving over pubsub.